# Does a registry for fallen meteors exist?

Tags: meteorite

Is there any kind of like an officially monitored list of falling asteroids, meteors, etc and objects entering earth's atmosphere?

Comment: A list of all meteors would be hard to compile: you'd need a network of full-sky cameras every 100 km or so to get them all. There are lists of objects that make it to land (meteorites), AFAIK meteors are tracked in the aggregate only (i.e. we know when the major meteor showers occur).

Comment: See for example this open access paper: http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/2015GL065149/full

Comment: if they have fallen they are not meteors but meteorites,most fall in the water liquid or frozen,away from populated areas so they are never registered.

Comment: There are fairly curated lists of reports of fireballs kept at [JPL's Center for Near Earth Object Studies](https://cneos.jpl.nasa.gov/fireballs/) and [the American Meteor Society](https://www.amsmeteors.org/fireballs/fireball-report/).

Comment: @JeopardyTempest can you upgrade that to an answer?

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is "yes" and the links are provided below.

Fireball reports: https://www.amsmeteors.org/fireballs/fireball-report/
Classified meteorites: https://www.lpi.usra.edu/meteor/